# 22.04 32 Bit Server Edition Raspiberry Pi 4 / 4GB - Problem mounting a USB HDD

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, hard-drive, 22.04

I have the following problem and hope that maybe someone can help me.

I have a Raspberry 4 with 4GB RAM that I use as a media server with two USB hard drives (4TB and 18TB). Until now I have been running Ubuntu 22.04 64Bit Desktop Edition and there were no problems. To increase the performance I have now installed Ubuntu 22.04 32 Bit Server Edition because I do not need a graphical user interface and Gnome eats quite a bit of RAM. The problem now is that I can no longer mount the 18 TB HDD. When I start Gparted I get the two errors can be seen in the screenshots i posted

[image]

[image]

Now you could think that something is wrong with the partition table, but I have connected the hard drive to different computers and made file system checks there but no errors are displayed. I have tested this on another Pi, a notebook and a workstation, all say that there is nothing wrong with the hard drive and everything is fine. As I said before the installation, the hard drive was working fine on the Pi. Here are the logs from a clean fsck.ext4.

I hope anyone has an idea.

Thank you

```
sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/sdb1
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
/dev/sdb1: clean, 72382/274661376 files, 3892345840/4394573312 blocks


Device: /dev/sdb
Model:  WD Elements 25A3
Serial: 3MGPR7BU
Sector size:    512
Total sectors:  35156590592

Heads:  255
Sectors/track:  2
Cylinders:  68934491

Partition table:    gpt

Partition   Type    Start   End Flags   Partition Name  File System Label   Mount Point
/dev/sdb1   Primary 2048    35156588543 msftdata    Elements    ext4

========================================
Check and repair file system (ext4) on /dev/sdb1  00:01:17    ( SUCCESS )

calibrate /dev/sdb1  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sdb1 (partition)
start: 2048
end: 35156588543
size: 35156586496 (16.37 TiB)
check file system on /dev/sdb1 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:01:17    ( SUCCESS )

e2fsck -f -y -v -C 0 '/dev/sdb1'  00:01:17    ( SUCCESS )

Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

72382 inodes used (0.03%, out of 274661376)
4774 non-contiguous files (6.6%)
10 non-contiguous directories (0.0%)
# of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
Extent depth histogram: 60417/11956
3892345840 blocks used (88.57%, out of 4394573312)
0 bad blocks
562 large files

64096 regular files
8277 directories
0 character device files
0 block device files
0 fifos
0 links
0 symbolic links (0 fast symbolic links)
0 sockets
------------
72373 files
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
grow file system to fill the partition  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

resize2fs -p '/dev/sdb1'  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

resize2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
The filesystem is already 4394573312 (4k) blocks long. Nothing to do!
```

Some more Info, when i use gdisk on one of this computer where the usb hdd is working gdisk shows this:

GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.9

Partition table scan:
MBR: protective
BSD: not present
APM: not present
GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help):

On the not working Pi it looks like this:

GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Warning! Read error 27; strange behavior now likely!
Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating
backup header from main header.

Warning! Error 27 reading partition table for CRC check!
Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!
Main header: OK
Backup header: ERROR
Main partition table: OK
Backup partition table: ERROR

Partition table scan:
MBR: protective
BSD: not present
APM: not present
GPT: damaged

---

Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.

---

Command (? for help):

Comment: Does a 32 bit OS support drives that big?

Comment: I found the error. A 32Bit ARM Kernel can`t work with 18TB Drives. The 64Bit Kernel fixed the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Install a 64-bit version of Ubuntu. A 32-bit ARM Linux kernel doesn't work with 18TB hard drives.